# ARM Embedded Linux (AM335x), Text File Contents Deleted After Power Off

Tags: c++, linux, qt, arm, embedded-linux

Kernel: 3.12.30-AM335x-PD15.2.1 (by PHYTEC)

My application requires editing a text file on run time and using it contents next time it powers on. So I created a text file in which I write a simple text, "Disable" or "Enable" using the program I have written with QT C++.

What I realized is, after the program writes the simple text, if I use the command "reboot" on bash, and wait for the program to reboot before I power off the the system (by plugging off its cable), "cat TextFile.txt" command yields "Enable" or "Disable", whichever the program has last written correctly.

However if I don't do a reboot and power the system off right away, and then power on again, the text file remains but the contents are deleted, so "cat TextFile.txt" yields nothing.

I tried to do the same manually, using the below methods:

Method 1:

```
echo Disable > TextFile.txt
reboot
.....wait for it to reboot
cat TextFile.txt

The results is "Disable".
```

Method 2:

```
echo Disable > TextFile.txt
.. power off by plugging off the cable
.. power on the system
cat TextFile.txt

No resulting text..
```

I simply don't want to have to reboot the system for the files to be saved. So I would be happy with executing commands within my QT C++ program to save everything without a reboot; but I do not know the operating system very well, therefore I do not know what is it that I should do to be able to do this.

This is my code my by the way:

```
QFile file(filename);
    // Trying to open in WriteOnly and Text mode
    if(!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly |
                  QFile::Text))
    {
        qDebug() << " Could not open file for writing";
    }

    // To write text, we use operator<<(),
    // which is overloaded to take
    // a QTextStream on the left
    // and data types (including QString) on the right

    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << "Enable";
    file.flush();
    file.close();
```

Comment: Pulling the plug on a computer resulting in data loss should not come as a surprise. In terms of how to use Linux, rebooting is basically a very expensive way of running [`sync`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sync.1.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your experiement on the shell has shown this is not strictly a c++ or Qt matter, the file is just not written to disk right away.

The system setup is likely using delayed writing to optimize disk access times, i.e. first writing into in-memory buffers and writing to actual disk every once in a while.

You might want to tune that if you have other programs that write files and expect power loss as a realistic scenario.

Now, for the Qt program in question, you could try using `QSaveFile` instead of `QFile`, its `commit()` asks the system to actually sync to disk.

Comment: How could I tune it? I really need the file to be saved at most in 1 min. I will try the QSaveFile now.

Comment: QSaveFile worked excellently, just what I needed, thank you:)

Comment: for tuning: that depends on the filesystem in use: often through mount options, but some might require values to be set at kernel build time